# cmd.exe crashes instantly, while powershell runs correctly [Windows 10 20H1]

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I were trying to execute batch file on windows 10, but batch file didn't run. While trying to troubleshoot this issue, I found out that cmd.exe didn't run at all. When I try to run cmd.exe from powershell, cmd.exe crashes instantly after the welcome message.

This is what I've tried.

- I've ran `sfc /scannow` and `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` with no issues at all.
- I've started cmd with `Command Prompt` menu from the Start Menu, but it didn't work either.
- Some suggested to check the `PATH` environment variable. `$env.PATH` correctly has `C:\Windows\system32`. Full path below if needed.

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJDK-11-Full\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2021.3.1\;C:\Users\phu54\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\phu54\scoop\shims;C:\Users\phu54\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\phu54\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Users\phu54\go\bin;C:\Users\phu54\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\phu54\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\MPC-BE x64\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\BrowserStackLocal\;C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32;C:\Users\phu54\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin;
```

I really don't know where I should begin troubleshooting from, or what additional information should I include. Where should I look for? What information should I include? Thanks :)

- Windows 10 Pro, Version 21H1, OS build 19043.1387

---

**Edits: "Welcome message" & error code of `cmd.exe` executed by powershell.**  *(2nd & 3rd line is the welcome message part)*

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1387]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> echo $LASTEXITCODE
1
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

cmd.exe executes well when run through newly created user profile. If that's the only option I could migrate all my data, but I hope if there's another option.

In case `$env:PATH` is the issue, I tried to replicate `PATH` env variable of the new profile to the old profile with the code below. `$env:PATH` value is copied from when I logged in as a new profile, where the issue were resolved. I only changed the username to `phu54` (old profile's username)

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $env:PATH= "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJDK-11-Full\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2021.3.1\;C:\Users\phu54\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1387]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> echo $LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: Can you create an additional user on your computer, login as that user and start cmd? then you can find out if the problem is system-wide or user-wide. It could be a corrupt user profile. After the test, you can remove the testuser.

Comment: What welcome message exactly?

Comment: Your %PATH% environment variable is the most likely culprit, as it impacts DLL search order and loading precendence.  Move the first 4 paths after `C:\Windows\System\OpenSSH\ `.  The `C:\Windows` paths should always be listed first. Once reordered, reboot your system (required). Poorly written application installers are the main reasons %PATH% gets reordered incorrectly.  In your case, you can blame NVIDIA GPU Computing Tools, BellSoft LibericaJDK, and VMware Workstation installers.  Also, if you are on a domain-joined system, ensure no group policy or SRP is blocking cmd.exe (check event log)

Comment: How do you know it crashes. Do you get an error message?

Comment: @whyask37 - You absolutely can post an image.  You just can't make it in line within the body of the question.  You need to [edit] your question to include the information you are providing in your commentary and clarify what "welcome message" you are talking about exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnZu6HNmIiY. Thanks for the great video.

- Open `regedit.exe`
- Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`
- Remove `AutoRun` key

IDK who've put this key here in the first place. The issue is gone after this fix.